# fopen() does not working well with gvim editor

Tags: c, windows, vim

First, I can't speak ENGLISH very well.. please understand :)

When I try to open text file to write something using fopen() with gvim, e.g. `FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "w");`, I can't find the data.txt file anywhere.. not only current directory but in Windows Explorer. BUT..It's working fine without the file. :|

I had doubts, So I've tried this `FILE *f = fopen("c:\my\..."data.txt", "w");` Specify path, Working good!

I know that text file is stored in the same folder as in execution file folder.

Of course, Other IDE is working very well.(MSVS or Dev C++)
What's my problem??

(I'm using Windows7 and gvim.)

```
// Modification
// source code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = NULL;
    int name[10];

    if((f = fopen("data.txt", "w")) == NULL){
        printf("sorry..\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Dennis");
    fclose(f);

    if((f = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("sorry2..\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(f, "%s", name);
    printf("%s\n", name);

    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} // I think it's no problem. I've tried different ways to try several times.
```

I will compile this -> map :! gcc % -o %<.exe (in vimrc. file) Push Cntl + F9.
Vim 7.3, MingW 0.1-alpha-5.
I just coding some source code, there are fopen(), fprintf() and fscanf(). When I tried to write on text file that I opened file, something was written there. but I could not see the text file.
And, I tried to read the text file that I wrote file, although It was open, could not be read.
Windows Explorer could not find the text file.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the fact that you're using gvim.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in five or ten lines of code, that you can paste here?

Comment: Do I have to specify path every time? It's nuisance..

Comment: to sarnold. of course. but difficult to see that :)

Comment: if((f = fopen("data.txt", "w")) == NULL) { some warning and exit.. } fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Dennis"); fclose(f); if((f = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == NULL) {...} fscanf(f, "%s", name); fclose(f); // file does not exist, but working. It's all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess, but I think your problem is that gvim doesn't change into the directory of your file.

There's an easy remedy for that: [autochdir](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autochdir%27)

Try to use Windows's search application, to locate your data.txt. If you started gvim from the start menu, they should be in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Vim 7.3".

Comment: Thank you hynek :) autochdir is good answer! but I can't find data.txt. Is's mystery

Comment: I suppose it will be _somewhere_ in your file system. Try windows finder (press Windows-f). :)

Comment: I've tried it before(checked "Show hidden Files" in folder options). but I could not find...

Comment: Could you edit your question and detail exactly step by step what you do? It's kind of a guessing game to help you right now. How do you compile? How do you start the program? Which Compiler do you use?

Comment: Thank you for attention. I will be editing my question right now. :)

Comment: what does ":pwd" inside of vim tell? and is your data.txt there?

Comment: I think it's difficult to see and to understand. Please understand my effort :)

Comment: :pwd => c:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\Vim73. but there are no text files. there are associated files with vim.

Comment: You didn't mention, how you start your compiled program? But if you're using mingw and gcc. you can use POSIX, so simply add a "#include <unistd.h>" at the top and a "puts(getcwd(malloc(1024), 1023)" at the beginning of your main(). What does it say?

Comment: Oh! My mistake. I start compiled program this -> map <C-F10> :!%<.exe<CR>. Is this a problem? I will try it.:)

Comment: When I did setting autochdir => current folder(working). When I didn't setting autochdir => C:Program File <x86>\Vim\vim73, and could not find..

Comment: There's clearly a permission problem, because your program shouldn't be able to write to vim's folder. I just wonder why a) autochdir doesn't solve it and b) you don't get an error message. I remember very roughly some feature in Vista, that made several "versions" of files, if the program hadn't the permission to write. If autochdir doesn't solve your problem, I'm at the end of my wisdom unfortunately.

Comment: It's strange. No see, but open. And "autochdir" that your answer does solve it(somewhat(?)). and I know source of the problem because of you. Thank you!! Have a nice day!(I don't know your time.. :) )